# register_block_type( __DIR__ . '..........' ); Problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem, I am creating myself a block and styles for it. The php , which relates to the block render without a problem, but the styles change the path. However, when editing the post I can not see the styles because the value changes from blankslate-child/block.... somehow changes to the wrong path blankslate/-child/block - which causes a problem with loading styles during.

This is my JSON:

```json
{
    "name": "acf/partner",
    "title": "Partner",
    "description": "A custom partner block.",
    "style": [ "file:./partner.css" ],
    "category": "formatting",
    "icon": "admin-users",
    "keywords": ["partner", "quote"],
    "acf": {
        "mode": "preview",
        "renderTemplate": "partner.php"
    },
    "align": "full",
    "supports": {
        "align": true,
        "dimensions": true,
        "typography": true,
        "anchor": true,
        "alignContent": true,
        "color": {
            "text": true,
            "background": true,
            "link": true
        },
        "alignText": false,
        "fullHeight": false,
        "spacing": {
            "margin": true,  
            "padding": true, 
            "blockGap": true
        }
    },
    "attributes": {
        "backgroundColor": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "#ffffff"
          },
          "fontSize": {`your text`
            "type": "number",
            "default": 16
          }
    }
}
```

And this is what I have in functions.php :

```php
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/blocks/testimonial/block.json' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/blocks/partner/block.json' );
}
```

I went through all the code, checked the end points I am sure there is a bug somewhere, but I can't locate it. It looks like `__DIR__` is showing the wrong weight of my theme. I would like to fix the link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The issue appears to be with loading the CSS, but unfortunately the code you have shown us isn't enough to go on to help you debug the issue. I suggest you visit the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and after doing some debugging to narrow down the relevant code, you can post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the relevant code so we might be better placed to help.